# iOS 13 UIActivityViewController automatically present previous VC after image saving

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios13

I'm trying to implement “Save image to Library” function and then return back to the current view controller, but on a new iOS 13 it dismisses back to the view controller that presented the current one:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({(_ status: PHAuthorizationStatus) -> Void in })

let shareItems: Array = [newImg,"Hello"] as [Any]

let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)

if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = saveButton
}

present(activityController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Yes, I can confirm the same problem on iOS 13. I’d suggest you file a bug report.

Comment: Unrelated but there is no reason for the device check. You can set the `sourceView` regardless. But you should also set a `sourceRect`.

Comment: Interestingly, I notice that the bug only manifests itself if you choose to save the image. If you choose the other options, it appears to return back to the correct view controller.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. This even happens on a device running iOS 13 with an app built with Xcode 10.

Comment: Can confirm too. Any luck with this?

Comment: Same here. Xcode 10.1, running on iOS 13.0. Seen this bug in more than one site but no ideas how to fix it so far.

Comment: Same here. Xcode 11.1 running on iOS 13.1.3. No success with any of the solutions below.

Comment: This is a really good bug!

Comment: Seems fixed in iOS 14.4

Comment: Back in iOS 15.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can confirm that this bug is still present in iOS 13.3.1. The following workaround is a Swift version of [franze's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57798040/1821701). I prefer this approach, as it doesn't make any further assumptions on the view controller hierarchy and doesn't use method swizzling.

Using this additional `UIWindow` breaks the *Cancel* button of the `UIActivityViewController` on iOS 12 and earlier, so I added a check for the OS version.

```
private let activityWindow: UIWindow = {
  let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
  window.rootViewController = UIViewController()
  return window
}()

func showActivityController() {
  let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(/* ... */)
  activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {
     // ...
     UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.makeKeyAndVisible()       
  }

  // Use this workaround only on iOS 13
  if ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersion.majorVersion == 13 {
    activityWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
    activityWindow.rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true)
  } else {
    present(activityViewController, animated: true)
  }
}
```

**Update:** Apparently, this solution doesn't work reliably on iPads. It looks like on iPad the `UIActivityViewController` is presented differently and as soon as it's visible on screen, no touch events are registered, effectively freezing the app.

Comment: Thank you! Finally solved for my case. I've changed only this line `activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activity: UIActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in )}`

Comment: Upon further testing, I noticed that my original solution doesn't work correctly on iOS 12 and earlier - please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Theo Im assuming that this is implemented into the .m file of the plugin but i am struggling to find where, i have tried bypassing the getTopMostViewController function but it just breaks it could you show where you implemented this to overwrite the standard view. thank you in advance

Comment: @troggy69 Implement the method in the view controller that presents the `UIActivityViewController`. Then, instead of calling `present(activityViewController, animated: true)`, call `showActivityViewController()` instead.

Comment: Please note my warning that I just added - this solution doesn't work on iPad. If someone knows how to fix it, I'd appreciate edits/comments.

Comment: @Theo not sure if this will help for you but the issue i have found with ipad is that it shows behind the view so on open you need to add (depending on your variables)  `ref.show();` on mine i had to add `ref.hide()` first. i doubt this will be what you need but might shed some insight

Comment: Also in regards to my implementation question i apologise as i worded it very badly, my app is a cordova app and i am trying to implement your fix into `cordova-plugin-file-opener2` into the .m file in the ios folder i believe the code style is objective c from what i can tell as i havent been coding apps for very long

Comment: it doesn't work - the app is frozen after dismissing activity controller

Comment: Update: For iOS 14 - `majorVersion == 14`

Comment: This solution cause some issues in my case. It acts weird after dismissing and presenting for further times.

Comment: I can confirm that this bug is still present in iOS 14 beta 3. I have filed a bug report FB8111145.

Comment: @troggy69 can you please help out with your code, I just wanted to know which view you hide in iPad?

Answer (score 12):

Swift version of @KDP's solution:

```
let fakeViewController = TransparentViewController()
fakeViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { [weak fakeViewController] _, _, _, _ in
    if let presentingViewController = fakeViewController?.presentingViewController {
        presentingViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    } else {
        fakeViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
present(fakeViewController, animated: true) { [weak fakeViewController] in
    fakeViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

`fakeViewController` gets either dismissed by activity completion, or we need to dismiss it in completion.

Comment: Great, this works flawlessly, thx!. The same issue as in iOS 13 is on iOS 14 btw.

Answer (score 4):

I generated following monkey patch (Checked by iOS 13.1.2)

```c
- (void)export {

  //
  // ... Generate Your Activity Items ...
  //

  UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                                                                           applicationActivities:nil
                                                                                                   completeBlock:^(NSError *activityError, BOOL completed) {
                                                                                                       // Swizzling Dismiss Method
                                                                                                       [[self class]   switchInstanceMethodFrom:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:) To:@selector(lockedDismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)];
                                                                                                   }
                                                                                ];
  // Swizzling Dismiss Method
  [[self class] switchInstanceMethodFrom:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:) To:@selector(lockedDismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)];
  [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)lockedDismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
    if ([self presentedViewController]) {
        [self lockedDismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
    }
}

// from http://qiita.com/paming/items/25eaf89e4f448ab05752
+(void)switchInstanceMethodFrom:(SEL)from To:(SEL)to
{
    Method fromMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self,from);
    Method toMethod   = class_getInstanceMethod(self,to  );
    method_exchangeImplementations(fromMethod, toMethod);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way I worked around this bug for now.  I create a fake view controller and push it onto the current stack.  It seems that UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll dismisses the top view controller on the stack, whereas the other options do not.  I take care of dismissing the fake view controller in the completion block if the activity type is not complete and UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll.

```
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

[self.activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
        if (activityType== UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll && completed){
              weakSelf.activityViewController = nil;
        }
        else{
             [weakSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
             weakSelf.activityViewController = nil;       
        }
}];


UIViewController *fakeVC=[[UIViewController alloc] init];

[self presentViewController:fakeVC animated:NO completion:^{
       [fakeVC presentViewController:self.activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
- (UIWindow *)displayWindow
{
    if (!_displayWindow)
    {
        _displayWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
        _displayWindow.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return _displayWindow;
}

- (void)showActivityController
{
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[] applicationActivities:nil];
    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(UIActivityType __nullable activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray * __nullable returnedItems, NSError * __nullable activityError)
    {
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    };

    [self.displayWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.displayWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:activityViewController animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

Make sure the `_displayWindow` is strong reference.

Comment: I implemented an equivalent solution and it has worked well so far.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by setting the root view controller to the current window, I have no idea why it dismisses the current view controller. I noticed that while presenting the new view controller in iOS 13 it will present to the card stack up style and if I chose "Save Image" in UIActivityController then the current view controller (card) will be dismissed and show up the previous view controller.

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
      let window = appDelegate.window else { return }
window.rootViewController = viewcontroller
```

I use this one instead of presenting view controller when I need to start a new story.

BTW, it depends on your requirements. In this case, I can dismiss the old unused one because no need to back, maybe you can use this instead of presenting a new scene.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's fixed in iOS 14. For older versions I found easier workaround via overriding `dismiss(animated:)` method with empty implementation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66595125/2095408

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, therefore I altered the way the viewcontroller was displayed.

Calling the share button's viewcontroller presents a problem for me.

I was calling share button's viewcontoller with
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bbZU.png)
self.present(.......) then  I change it

self.view.window.rootviewcontroller = share button's viewcontoller

and fixed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

For those who gets the screen freezes on iPads, here a simple solution. It works on iPhone too.

```
func shareItems(_ sharedItems: [Any]) {

        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: sharedItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        if let popoverController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2, width: 0, height: 0)
            popoverController.sourceView = self.view
            popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
        }

        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```