# UIActivityViewController dismissing current view controller after sharing file

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad

UIActivityViewController dismisses the presenting view controller after sharing files.
this is happening in iOS 13+ only. Is there any permanent solution for this?
Others apps seem to have this issue too after updating to iOS 13.

```
   class VC : UIViewController {


   @IBAction func moveFiles(_ sender: UIButton) {

      let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)


    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Move", style: .default, handler: { action in

    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: urls, applicationActivities: nil)


   if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad) {
   activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.frame
    activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender.superview
    }
   self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }))




           }


     }
```

Comment: can you show your complete class, please?

Comment: why would that matter? this code works fine in iOS 12 and under.

Comment: most probably you have written self dismiss in completion of activity block. It's better if you can share some code here.

Comment: Possibly related: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119482
Also sample project that reproduces this issue: https://github.com/iMacHumphries/TestShareSheet

Answer (score 3):

Here is the work around for your issue.

```
let tempController = TransparentViewController()
tempController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { [weak tempController] _, _, _, _ in
  if let presentingViewController = tempController?.presentingViewController {
    presentingViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
  } else {
    tempController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
  }
}

present(tempController, animated: true) { [weak tempController] in
    tempController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found similar question with solution which helps me. For iOS 13 show `UIActivityViewController` in another `UIWindow`
[Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61032571/5648975)

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's fixed in iOS 14.4

For older iOS versions I found easier workaround. Override `dismiss(animated:completion:)` with empty implementation so it won't be dismissing itself automatically.
However, you can still dismiss this VC using `super.dismiss(animated:completion)`.

E.g

```
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    // do nothing to workaround bug - automatically dimisses this VC after saveToCameraRoll activity was performed
    // call super.dismiss(animated:completion:) in order to really dismiss this VC
    // seems fixed in iOS 14.4
}

...

@objc private func didTapCloseButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    super.dismiss(animated: true) // calling parent class implementation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue right now on iOS target 14.1.
I made my solution based on answers I found.

```
final class ShareViewController: UIViewController {

private let activityItems: [Any]
private let applicationActivities: [UIActivity]?

// Same looking initializer as UIActivityViewController has
init(activityItems: [Any], applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil) {
    self.activityItems = activityItems
    self.applicationActivities = applicationActivities
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    // Make transparent and covering entire screen
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // Present UIActivityViewController here
    presentShareSheet()
}


fileprivate func presentShareSheet() {
    let shareSheet = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems,
                                              applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
    shareSheet.completionWithItemsHandler = { [weak self] _, _, _, _ in
        // This is necessary to dismiss parent VC
        self?.dismiss(animated: false)
    }
    self.present(shareSheet, animated: true)
}
}
```

And use it like UIActivityViewController but presenting it without animations

```
@objc private func shareImage() {
    guard let image = imageView.image else { return }
    let shareVC = ShareViewController(activityItems: [image])
    present(shareVC, animated: false)
}
```